# elasticsearch issue in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 system with 4 GB RAM and 500 GB hard disk.

I have installed elastic search in my system with :

```
sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

but while starting an elastic search with the command :

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

My system getting stuck, I am unable to do anything. How to fix this?